# Need recommendation on java development tools

Tags: java

I am new to Java and really impressed with it. I am interested in leveraging the latest java technology, however, not from an enterprise standpoint.  I want to leverage the latest technology from a small business development point of view. I feel that the small mom and pop grocery store can enhance their operational effectiveness by using the new Java technology, obviously not on an enterprise scale. If my thinking here is incorrect and if there is a school of thought that the current Java technologies is not designed for the small business person (which consist of 80% of the businesses today), I can accept that.  **If not, then 
what Java development framework, tools, skills, etc; do you recommend as a minimum for small business development?**

Jerry McLeod

Comment: There is no answerable question here. I feel it would be unethical to be recommending technologies and tools without knowing your problem space and requirements - as a software engineer, I have to act in your best interests. Unless I know what you want to achieve, I can't present options for going down any roads to achieving it.

Comment: Downvoted as I don't think A its an answerable question.  The user asks for frameworks without saying what type of software he is trying to build.

Answer (score 4):

Frameworks, tools, languages and skills are all designed for *tasks*, therefore it's relatively meaningless to talk about the organisation instead of about the tasks which an organisation might wish to perform.  A kid in garage could use every piece of Java Enterprise software available just as well as a Fortune 500 company could choose to use PHP.

So in essence, your question doesn't make a lot of sense without reference to what you might want to do with it.  It's true that a small business is unlikely to want many of the large-scale features that Java can offer, but it doesn't mean they can't use them if it's appropriate for the task at hand!

Answer (score 3):

Tools should fit the task at hand; the task at hand should not be defined so as to use the latest tools.

What tasks need to be done for small businesses? If I were just working on a website, I'd probably use PHP. But I have no idea what you're looking for.

Comment: Like Jason said, choosing a technology or tool and then trying to use those to solve a problem is the wrong approach. You need to define your problems and requirements of the systems first. Then, existing developed solutions, tools, and technologies that you can leverage become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Core framework for Java (Web) Development is [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) and [Apache Commons libraries](http://commons.apache.org/). And same for database access is [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). As development tools I would suggest [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts) and for web application deployment [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). And my favorite build tool is [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

But all this can variate what you would like to develop.

Answer (score 0):

you should watch out with getting flooded in al sorts of skills, frameworks, tools you start learning. That might become a huge confusion. Basically if you want me to spam with words,  I'd say you definately need

J2EE, JAAS, Spring and hibernate.

As a person I would recommend you to learn OO programming first if you are not familiar with java. I think there is little use in these tools if you don't know how to use java. I would start with reading Design patterns - Head first, and Effective java, to explore what OO is really all about. You can't get into business development (how small it is even...) except if you do it together with someone who knows what he does.

but that's just my thoughts

Comment: Well to be clear JSF is part of JEE, isn't it?

Comment: that's right. Now i'm even being confusing myself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why would Mom&Pops care if it's Java, C++ or ASM? Second of all you didn't really tell us what you want to achieve. Do you want to create web applications or standalone apps? For the latter you just need Java SE+any framework needed to get a certain job done. If you want to do webapps then it gets a bit hectic. Some people already mentioned Java EE, Spring, Hibernate etc. but there's also EJB (well it's part of the Java EE), Struts and so on.

Some might say java isn't well suited for small web apps, well I can't agree with that. JSF+Spring+Hibernate and you can get a simple usefull webapp up and running in 2-4weeks.